# The result returned is incorrect when retrieving data in the database

Tags: php, laravel, database

I am using laravel to create a website and I am getting an error that getting data from database does not return correct results, what did I do wrong

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $filter = $request->get('filter');
    $search = $request->get('q');
    $items = [];
    if ($filter === 'default' || empty($filter)){
        $query = DB::table(DBNAME::$DB_NAME)->
        where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        where('active',true)->orderByDesc('id');
        $items = $this->getData($query);
    }elseif($filter === 'free'){
        $query = DB::table(DBNAME::$DB_NAME)->
        where('active',true)->
        where('price',0)->
        where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->orderByDesc('id');
        $items = $this->getData($query);
    }elseif($filter === 'low_to_high_price'){
        $query = DB::table(DBNAME::$DB_NAME)->
        where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        where('active',true)->orderBy('price');
        $items = $this->getData($query);
    }elseif($filter === 'high_to_low_price'){
        $query = DB::table(DBNAME::$DB_NAME)->
        where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        where('active',true)->orderByDesc('price');
        $items = $this->getData($query);
    }
    elseif($filter === 'from_new_to_old'){
        $query = DB::table(DBNAME::$DB_NAME)->
        where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        where('active',true)->orderByDesc('created_at');
        $items = $this->getData($query);
    }elseif($filter === 'from_old_to_new'){
        $query = DB::table(DBNAME::$DB_NAME)->
        where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
        where('active',true)->orderBy('created_at');
        $items = $this->getData($query);
    }
    return APP::createResponseJson(true,__('strings.success'),$items);
}
private function getData($query,$i=0,$items=[]){
    foreach ($query->get() as $item){
        $items[$i]['title']=$item->title;
        $items[$i]['thumbnail']=$item->thumbnail;
        $items[$i]['description']=$item->description;
        $items[$i]['price']=$item->price;
        $items[$i]['sale']=$item->sale;
        $items[$i]['tags']=$item->tags;
        $items[$i]['created_at']=$item->created_at;
        $items[$i]['updated_at']=$item->updated_at;
        $i++;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

I have sent requests to the following links:

**http://localhost:8000/api/search**

**http://localhost:8000/api/search?filter=free**

**http://localhost:8000/api/search?filter=default&q=abcd**

I got the same result

Currently in my database there is only 1 data

```
{
"status": true,
"message": "Success",
"data": [{
    "title": "example",
    "thumbnail": null,
    "description": "description example",
    "price": 100,
    "sale": 0,
    "tags": "tag1,tag2,tag3",
    "created_at": "2022-04-12 13:34:22",
    "updated_at": null
}]
}
```

Comment: ensure `$filter` and/or `$search` are set in your URLs or define the cases if these are not set in  `public function search(Request $request)`. Also it'll be good for you to write what would you expect as output & what has given by the script to get help.

Comment: @Ersin I tried
`die($filter)` and `die($search)` it outputs correctly

Comment: http://localhost:8000/api/search?filter=default&q=abcd, could you please print SQL query in the first case and show us? I think your SQL query needs some amendment.

Comment: @Sachin $query->toSql():
```select * from `extensions` where `title` LIKE ? or `description` LIKE ? or `tags` LIKE ? and `active` = ? order by `id` desc```

Comment: You mean this
select * from `extensions` where `title` LIKE '%abcd%' or `description` LIKE '%abcd%' or `tags` LIKE '%abcd%' and `active` = true order by `id` desc ??

Comment: @Sachin that's right

Comment: Your sql query should be select * from `extensions` where (`title` LIKE '%abcd%' or `description` LIKE '%abcd%' or `tags` LIKE '%abcd%') and (`active` = true) order by `id` desc.
Run this query in phpmyadmin, I hope you will get right result.

Comment: That's great. Please upvote my comment if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

replace:

```
$query = DB::table(DBNAME::$DB_NAME)->
    where('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
    orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
    orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
    where('active',true)->orderByDesc('id');
```

to:

```
$query = DB::table(DBNAME::$DB_NAME)->
            where(function($query) use ($search){
            $query->orWhere('title','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
            orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->
            orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');
         
        })->where('active',true)
       ->orderByDesc('id');
```

and now it's working fine

I found it at: [Multiple orWhere Condition in Laravel Eloquent](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/multiple-orwhere-condition-in-laravel-eloquentexample.html)